# Nested multilayered async/await doesn't seem to wait

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have a piece of code simplified version of which looks like this:

```
let dataStorage1; //declare global vars for easier access later on
let dataStorage2;
let stopLight = true; //this variable is used to 'mark' an iteration as successful (= true) or
//failed (= false) and in need of a retry before continuing to the next 
//iteration
let delay = 2000; //the standard time for a delay between api calls

async function tryFetch() {
  try {
    dataStorage1 = await api.fetch('data_type_1'); //fetch needed data trough api, which
    //fills the global variable with an 
    //object
    dataStorage2 = await api.fetch('data_type_2'); //do the same
    stopLight = true; //change the value of stopLight to true, thus marking this iteration
    //as successful
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    stopLight = false;
  }
}

async function fetchData() {
  stopLight = true; //change the stopLight to default before execution

  await tryFetch(); //fetch data and assign it to variables

  //this section is needed for retrial of fetching after a 2s delay if the first attempt was
  //unsuccessful, which is repeated until it's either successful or critical error occurred
  while (stopLight == false) {
    setTimeout(async () => await tryFetch(), delay);
  }
}

(async function main() {
  await fetchData(); //finally call the function
  setTimeout(main, delay); //repeat the main function after 2s
})();
```

As you can see, self-executing, pseudo-recursive `main()` calls for `await fetchData()`, then `fetchData()` calls for `await tryFetch()` and finally `tryFetch()` calls for `await api.fetch('~')`, as it's defined in the api.

However, once I started the script and paused it after a couple of iterations, I noticed that both `dataStorage1` and `dataStorage2` remain `undefined`. If I go through the code step by step in debugger, what happens is that the execution starts at the beginning of `fetchData()`, moves to the `await tryFetch();` line, skips it, and then goes onto the next iteration.

For the reference, if I call `` dataStorage1/2 = await api.fetch(`~`); `` in the body of `main()` directly without any nesting, it works perfectly (unless error occurs, since they are not handled properly).

So, my question is what have I missed?

Comment: Not an answer, but two points you might like to consider: (1) the catch-throw-catch-try_again interplay between `fetchData()` and `tryFetch()` can be avoided by making `tryFetch()` recursive; (2) if `api.fetch('data_type_1')` and `api.fetch('data_type_2')` are liable to failure, then doing both fetches at every attempt maximises the chance of failure. The chance of `tryFetch()` being successful will be increased by putting `dataStorage1` or `dataStorage2` "in the bank" at each attempt (which is simple). If the fetches are reliable then there's very little penalty in taking that precaution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, if in an `async` function you call `setTimeout` you cannot expect it to perform an `await` on anything that relates to the callback passed to `setTimeout`. The call to `setTimeout` returns immediately, and your `while` loop is effectively a *synchronous* loop. It is a so called "busy loop" -- blocking your GUI as it potentially will loop for thousands of times.

As a rule of thumb, use `setTimeout` only *once*: to define a `delay` function, and then never again.

Also avoid using a global variable like `stopLight`: this is bad practice. Let the async function return a promise that *resolves* when this is supposed to be true, and *rejects* when not.

```
// Utility function: the only place to use setTimeout
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function tryFetch() {
    try {
        let dataStorage1 = await api.fetch('data_type_1'); 
        let dataStorage2 = await api.fetch('data_type_2'); 
        return { dataStorage1, dataStorage2 }; // use the resolution value to pass results
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        // retry
        throw err; // cascade the error!
    }
}

async function fetchData() {
    while (true) {
        try { 
            return await tryFetch(); // fetch data and return it
        } catch (err) {} // repeat loop
    }
}

(async function main() {
    let intervalTime = 2000; //the standard time for a delay between api calls

    while (true) { // for ever
        let { dataStorage1, dataStorage2 } = await fetchData();
        // ... any other logic that uses dataStorage1, dataStorage2
        //     should continue here...
        await delay(intervalTime); //repeat the main function after 2s
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this line: `setTimeout(async () => await tryFetch(), delay);`. The `await` statement inside the callback makes the promise returned by that callback wait, not the whole function. So `async () => await tryFetch()` is a function that returns a promise, but nothing waits for that promise to complete.

Try replacing that code with something line

```
await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
await tryFetch();
```